# Flutter/dart capture entire partially OFFSCREEN widget as image

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

Some comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50351442/6047611) suggest that it is possible to capture every pixel of a widget, even if it is partially offscreen. Comments in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51118092/6047611) suggest the opposite. I haven't been able to figure it out, I've only started messing with it today. Here's the code I have so far:

```
RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
```

Anyone know how to modify this so it will capture the full widget? Or does this only work with the portions of the widget that are on-screen?

FWIW, the answer provided in a similar question marking this one as duplicate is self-described as intentionally breaking things that flutter does for optimization, and only in worst-case scenario. I'm looking for an answer that doesn't have to do crazy stuff that will break in 2 years.

Comment: hey check this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53646649/how-to-take-screenshot-of-widget-beyond-the-screen-in-flutter>?