# Screenshot Widget Clipping My List View in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a List View that is inside a Screenshot widget that takes a screenshot of it each time a function is executed. It works fine, but my issue is that after a certain number of items on the List View (in this case 10+), the screenshot that is taken clips them after that number,it only takes a screenshot of visible items on the screen at the time. Is there a way to take the whole screen as a screenshot? Here's the code:

**SCREENSHOT**

```
body: Screenshot(
        controller: screenshotController,
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              SingleChildScrollView(
              ---- list items here ----
```

**HOW THE IMAGE IS DISPLAYED**

```
 return showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          child: InteractiveViewer(
            boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.zero,
            minScale: 1,
            maxScale: 4,
            child: AlertDialog(
              content: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage(url), fit: BoxFit.contain)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
```

So basically, am I doing something wrong here, since the screenshot taken only takes a screenshot of visible screen and not the whole body as I tried to put in code (it only takes a picture of visible List View items on the screen, everything over 10 items is clipped).

Comment: You can check these two: [How to take a screenshot of widget beyond the screen in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53646649/how-to-take-screenshot-of-widget-beyond-the-screen-in-flutter/58120162#58120162), [how to capture a scrollview](https://github.com/SachinGanesh/screenshot/issues/10)

Answer (score 1):

Make it Insdie the Column then it will auto work .

```
Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              child: Column(
    children[
     ListView(
    
    ]
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the code doesn't show anything there. I tried putting screenshot on different parts, but it still cuts off the list view.

Comment: if you put it into Column then it will not cuts off the list view

Comment: not, it´s not work.