# How to take a screenshot in Flutter of a widget bigger than the height of the mobile screen?

Tags: flutter, screenshot, staggered-gridview

I am using an invisible widget StaggeredGridView which is bigger than the height of the emulator/mobile. The image is rendering only a part of it, I didn't find any answer relevant to this problem

```
  screenshotController
     .captureFromWidget(
       StaggeredGridView.count(
         crossAxisCount: 4,
         staggeredTiles: _staggeredTiles,
         children: _tiles,
       ),)
     .then((capturedImage) {
   // Handle captured image
   ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
       Uint8List.fromList(capturedImage),
       quality: 90,
       name: "WomanVerseWallpaper");
 });
```

The screen which I want to take a screenshot of the widget (bigger than the screen, it continues)
[image]

What I'm getting

[image]

Comment: Duplicated question please checkout this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53646649/how-to-take-screenshot-of-widget-beyond-the-screen-in-flutter